# Arithmetic coding - min. number of bits

Tags: encoding, decoding

Is it possible to somehow calculate minimum number of bits that are needed to represent integers in arithmetic coding? Let's say i have 100characters-length string. How many bits do i need to encode and decode that sequence?

Comment: It depends on the frequency table for those 100 characters

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Is it any formula or any way to count amount of those bits?

Comment: Yes. Use the standard formula for calculating information entropy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#Definition